# Cannot add tags to frontend views Django queryset

Tags: django, django-views, tags

I'm trying to add tags to my view from a query set column that looks like this for one observation like synonyms for great:

```
  ['fun, cool, awesome']
```

When I try to display as separated tags, it just prints as one block:

```
  'fun, cool, awesome'
```

This is what views.py looks like passing this data:

```
class SynDetailView(generic.DetailView):
     model = Syn
     template_name = "synonoms/syn_detail.html"

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SynDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tags  = Syn.objects.filter('synid'=self.kwargs.get('pk')).values_list('tags', flat=True)
        tags = str(tags)
        context['tags'] = [x.strip() for x in tags.split(',')]
        return context
```

EDIT:  I want to print them like this

```
'fun'
'cool'
'awesome'
```

Comment: What's exactly your question? How do you print that array in your template?

Comment: Can you share your existing template file?

Answer (score 1):

rather than converting them to string and splitting them, you can directly send the list values like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SynDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['tags'] = Syn.objects.filter('synid'=self.kwargs.get('pk')).values_list('tags', flat=True)
    return context
```

Then you can strip the value in template as well:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    {{ tag.strip }}
{% endfor %}
```